# Что означают такие понятия как: консоль, терминал, эмулятор терминала?

Tags: консоль, эмулятор, терминал

Никак не могу чётко осознать структуру взаимосвязей между этими понятиями, поэтому прошу упор в ответе делать не на свойства, а сразу на суть вещей.

Comment: связанный вопрос [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/1321)

Answer (score 3):

Терминал - это устройство, при помощи которого человеки взаимодействуют с компьютером. Например, через банковский терминал можно взаимодействовать с банковским компьютером.

Эмулятор терминала - это программа, которая выдаёт себя за терминал, но на деле им не является. Она может отличаться от настоящего терминала интерфейсом, архитектурой, функционалом, чем угодно. Главное, что компьютер считает её терминалом.

Консолями называют обобщённо терминалы и их эмуляторы.

Comment: @akp "взаимодействует" - значит является устройством ввода/вывода, имея определённый программный интерфейс для обмена информацией (API). Эмулятор именно тем и отличается, что ему этот API известен. В отличии от "консоли", которые являются довольно обобщённым и размытым понятием. Например, консоль браузера не имеет отношения к терминалам и эмуляторам, она просто внешне на них похожа.

Comment: Вообще, консолями сейчас что только не называют. Я затрудняюсь дать точное определение консоли.

Comment: PS и Xbox, внезапно, тоже консоли. И балконообразный выступ здания — консоль.