# как переименовать коммит в github?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Недавно начал ознакомление с git и github. Могу ли я переименовать commit, уже пропушеный на гитхабе? Знаю, что для этого используют git commit --amend -m "Some info". Только вот куда это вписывать? Долго рылся в интернете и не смог найти внятного объяснения. Использую расширение для VS, также есть десктопная версия гитхаба.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да) https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/7/e2a913473ea815245a283f49e12be4ac-full.png

Comment: если в проекте кроме вас никого нет, то сделайте локально `git commit --amend -m "Some info"` и затем `git push --force`

Comment: если работаете не один, то посоветуйтесь с другими контрибьюторами - может это не так критично

Comment: чем вы пользуетесь для управления гитом? клиентом гитхаба, командной строкой, что-то еще?

Comment: пока что пользуюсь расширением для VS. так вопрос стоял в том, куда вписывать git commit --amend -m "Some info" и  git push --force ? Вопрос был в этом)

Comment: так вот вы и добавьте в вопрос информацию об инструменте, которым работаете с гит, потому как через командный интерфейс везде работает одинаково, а вот через гуи везде по-разному

Comment: также есть десктопная версия гитхаба

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Для выполнения команд git используется так называемая «консоль» — интерпретатор команд на специальном языке. На Linux/Unix/OS X консоль работает с языками семейства Sh ([sh](/questions/tagged/sh), [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)...), на Windows есть cmd.exe ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)) и PowerShell ([powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)), но вместе с Git ставится Git Bash – интерпретатор bash с базовым набором программ.

> Подробнее: [Что означают такие понятия как: консоль, терминал, эмулятор терминала?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719402/181472)

---

## Не всегда коммит можно переименовывать

Пока коммит не попал на удаленный репозиторий, с ним можно делать что угодно.

Ваш коммит уже попал на удаленный репозиторий, в ветку `master`. Если кто-то ещё использует этот репозиторий, переименовывать коммиты нельзя, потому что при переименовании фактически создается новый коммит.

В вашем случае похоже, что вы работаете над учебным заданием в собственном репозитории, поэтому вреда не будет.

---

## Как переименовать коммит и отправить новое состояние на GitHub

Предположим, что есть вот такая история коммитов. На локальном и удаленном сервере одна и та же история:

```
локальный: A---B (master)

удаленный: A---B (origin/master)
```

Для переименования коммита действительно нужно выполнить команду.

```
git commit --amend -m 'Новое сообщение'
```

Стало после `--amend`:

```
локальный: A---B2 (master) # совершенно другой коммит, хоть и с тем же содержимым)
            \
             B # не удален, но больше не принадлежит ветке master.
               # можно восстановить через git reflog

удаленный: A---B (origin/master)
```

После этого придётся явным образом переписать ветку `master` на удаленном репозитории (на GitHub). Поскольку история коммитов разошлась, GitHub не примет изменения просто так, нужно добавить ключ `--force`:

```
git push --force origin <имя ветки на удаленном репозитории>
```

Было:

```
локальный: A---B2 (master) 
            \
             B

удаленный: A---B (origin/master)
```

Стало после `push --force`:

```
удаленный: A---B2 (origin/master)
            \
             B # вообще недоступен, потому что у вас нет доступа к файловой системе гитхаба
               # уберется сборщиком мусора на сервере
```

> **Осторожно:** в общем случае команда `push --force` опасна, так как переписывает состояние ветки на удаленном репозитории и может привести к потерям.
>
> Например, если кто-то добавит свой коммит в ветку `master`, а потом вы переименуете свою ветку и сделаете `push --force`, то чужой коммит будет потерян.
>
> Было:

```
локальный: A---B2 (master) 
            \
             B

удаленный: A---B---С (origin/master)
```

> Стало: чужой коммит C потерян, автор идёт к вам с недобрыми намерениями

```
удаленный: A---B2 (origin/master)
            \
             B---С # недоступен
```

Comment: "нельзя" :: можно! Просто чревато :) У нас ещё нет канонического вопроса на тему "чем опасен аменд"?

Comment: @D-side вроде есть чем опасен ребейз

Comment: *чужой коммит C потерян, автор идёт к вам с недобрыми намерениями* Коммит можно вытащить из `reflog` (по крайней мере в GitHub) так что не всё так ужасно.

Comment: Для примера https://github.com/archeski/ProblemSet_3/commits/master@%7B1%7D или https://github.com/archeski/ProblemSet_3/commits/master@%7B2017-11-6%7D